# Doctrine querybuilder, include elements in ManytoMany relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-query

I have a Symfony form type class like this:

```
$builder->add('blockedUsers', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => User::class,
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.isActive=1')
            // error:
            ->orWhere('u.id IN (SELECT user_id FROM offer_blockedusers WHERE offer_id=:offer_id)')
            ->setParameter(':offer_id', $options['offer_id'])
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
    'label' => 'Blocked users',
    'required' => false,
    'multiple' => true,
    'choice_label' => 'username'
])
```

Basically, this entity (called Offer) can have some blockedUsers:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *  name="offer_blockedusers",
 *  joinColumns={
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 *  },
 *  inverseJoinColumns={
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 *  }
 * )
 */
private $blockedUsers;
```

And the admin can allow/block an offer for some users:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O5nk.png]

In this dropdown, I want to show only the active users, **plus** the users that are already blocked for that offer. (because a user can become inactive if he doesn't log in for a long time, but he must continue to be blocked)

My try above doesn't work because I get

> Class 'offer_blockedusers' is not defined.

Since it's not an entity, but a join table.

Can I do this with a DQL or I should switch to native SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Without having tested it, I think that you are looking something like this:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Offer', 'of', 'WITH', 'of.id = :offer_id')
        ->where('u.isActive = 1')
        ->orWhere('of.id IS NOT NULL')
        ->setParameter(':offer_id', $options['offer_id'])
        ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
```

The basic problem is that you are not joining the offers table.